# Lax-Milgram theorem - why do we need Sobolev spaces?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This is a special case of "why do we need Sobolev spaces". There seem to be good general answers to the question here (I believe I read some), but too high-level for me (I didn't really get the point yet). So here's a more specific question.

In my understanding, we are using Sobolev spaces because we want to find a "less regular" solution to a PDE that has no classical solution (that is, one with sufficiently many well-behaved derivatives).

However, if we have a problem in weak formulation, represented as B[u,v] = (f,v) $\forall v \in H$ where H is a Hilbert space, and the requirements of the [Lax-Milgram theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation#The_Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem) fulfilled , can we not choose both a fitting Sobolev Space (e.g. $H = H^1((0,1))$) OR also a fitting "truly" differentiable space, e.g.:

- $H = F$ := {$f \in C^0((0,1))$ | $f' \in L^2((0,1))$}?

Doesn't Lax-Milgram also guarantee a solution lying in $F$ ? So why make use of Sobolev spaces here?  (We cannot use $C^\infty$ since it is not complete, and Lax-Milgram won't apply.)

Comment: What does your "truly differentiable" mean? Normal derivation does not apply to $L^2$ functions so we have to use distributive derivation, but that yields precisely the Sobolev spaces.

Comment: The spaces of $C^k$ functions are not complete for the integral norms (which are the norms necessary for weak formulations), only the sup norms,

Comment: @Zerox it stumped me initially too due to the way it was written, but I think OP just means $F=\{f:(0,1)\to\Bbb{R}\,|\, \text{$f$ is $C^1$ on $(0,1)$ and $f,f'\in L^2(0,1)$}\}$, or maybe even just $\tilde{F}=\{f:(0,1)\to\Bbb{R}\,|\, \text{$f$ is (classically pointwise everywhere) differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $f,f'\in L^2(0,1)$}\}$.

Comment: @ Zerox, @peek-a-boo: Sorry, yes there was a mistake /inconsistency: Of course F must contain only continuous functions else no derivative exists. But I'd require $C^0$, not $C^1$ and instead $f' \in L^2$. So the second of peek-a-boo 's spaces it is, yes.

Comment: @Zerox, with "truly differentiable" I mean that we require a true derivative to exist everywhere in the (here) interval (0,1), so that f = integral of f' + f(0).

Comment: yes, so now you have the issue of lack of completeness (with respect to integral norms), which is why these spaces are unsuitable. The first space I proposed is complete atleast with respect to $C^1$-sup norm, but the second is not complete (as far as I can tell) with respect to any "obvious" norms. So...

Comment: Isn't $L^2((0,1))$ complete? I was thinking of using the Sobolev norm, $||f|| := ||f||_{L^2} + ||f'||_{L^2}$ .

Comment: Is there a problem with sequences where f' becomes too wild to be called a derivative? Such as f' that becomes pointier and pointier, while $||f'||_{L^2}$ stays the same?

Comment: Like I said before, neither of the spaces $(\tilde{F},\|\cdot\|_{H^1(0,1)})$ $(F,\|\cdot\|_{H^1(0,1)})$ is complete. $L^2$ is complete. $H^1$ is complete. But $F$ and $\tilde{F}$ are not complete subspaces. so you can’t apply Lax-Milgram. Hence, Sobolev spaces are our friends.

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe I understand this one reason for Sobolev spaces a lot better now.